# jQuery second click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My `HTML` structure

```
<tr class="">
<td class="day">20</td>
<td class="day">21</td>
<td class="day">22</td>
<td class="day">23</td>
<td class="day">24</td>
<td class="disabled day">25</td>
<td class="disabled day">26</td>
</tr>

<tr class="">
<td class="day">13</td>
<td class="day">14</td>
<td class="day">15</td>
<td class="day">16</td>
<td class="day">17</td>
<td class="disabled day">18</td>
<td class="disabled day">19</td>
</tr>
```

**jQuery Script**

```
<script>
$(function(){
        $(".day").click(function() {
        alert('Test');
        var first = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
        var last = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:last').text();
        $("span#date-range").append( "(Oct "+first+"- Oct "+last+")" );
    });
});
</script>
```

On page load, when user clicks on any `<td>`, it displays the correct value, but if user click on it again, it does nothing. Also after click, the `HTML` structure remains same but gets when seen in `Firebug Console`.

**First Click**

[image]

After First Click i.e. subsequent clicks

[image]

How can I enable multiple clicks on `<td>` for the above if it gets changed .

Thanks.

Comment: above code should work as it is for multiple time click... have you check console error. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ygcx972y/12/)

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6f37aymq/1/ - what is the expected behavior

Comment: Probably something else interferes, because above code is all right.

Comment: Pls see my edit. I have attached screenshots.

Comment: Can you show the errors please, your console is definitely showing some.

Comment: Well, it shows nothing. No errors though.

Comment: Have you tried running code in another browser?

Comment: Yes. its the same everywhere.

Comment: The best you can do here is to create a demo. Because obviously the problem is with something you are not covering in the question.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy dfsq is right. Try to recreate the issue in a demo and edit your post.

Comment: given code should work, it is not having any errors. May be you are missing something to post in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem can be solved by using .live or .on mehtod

```
$(function(){
        $(document).on('click','.day',function() {
        alert('Test');
        var first = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
        var last = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:last').text();
        $("span#date-range").append( "(Oct "+first+"- Oct "+last+")" );
    });
});
```

Comment: TypeError: $(...).live is not a function `$(".day").live('click',function() {`

Comment: which version of jquery r u using?

Comment: I have edidted my answer please check

Comment: I was just missing the `document onclick`.

Answer (score 1):

Your html table should be valid and it should work. See attached working snippet:

```js
$(function(){
        $(".day").click(function() {
        alert('Test');
        var first = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
        var last = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:last').text();
        $("span#date-range").append( "(Oct "+first+"- Oct "+last+")" );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="">
<td class="day">20</td>
<td class="day">21</td>
<td class="day">22</td>
<td class="day">23</td>
<td class="day">24</td>
<td class="disabled day">25</td>
<td class="disabled day">26</td>
</tr>
</table>
<tr class="">
<td class="day">13</td>
<td class="day">14</td>
<td class="day">15</td>
<td class="day">16</td>
<td class="day">17</td>
<td class="disabled day">18</td>
<td class="disabled day">19</td>
</tr>
</table>
```